# Ruby On Rails - Access the current_user attributes in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've made a restaurant guide, and I'm implementing a star rating system. Everything's good so far but now I'm having difficulties on the JQuery part that holds the number of stars the current user voted for the restaurant.
Here follows the relevant code:

SCHEMA -------------------------

```
  create_table "ratings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "star"
    t.integer "restaurant_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

MODELS -------------------------

Restaurant model:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :ratings
end
```

Rating model:

```
   class Rating < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :restaurant
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :ratings
end
```

CONTROLLERS --------------------

Ratings controller

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @rating = @restaurant.ratings.create(params[:rating].permit(:star))
    @rating.user = current_user
    @rating.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Obrigado pelo seu voto!'
    redirect_to restaurant_path(@restaurant)
  end
end
```

HTML ---------------------------

```
<ul class="rating pl-0">
  <% form_id = "restaurant_#{@restaurant.id}_rating"  %>
  <%= form_for([@restaurant, @restaurant.ratings.build], :html => {:id => "restaurant_#{@restaurant.id}_rating", :class => "star_rating_form"}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :restaurant_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :star, :id => "#{form_id}_stars" %>
  <% end %>
  <% (1..5).each do |i| %>
    <li class="rating_star mx-1 pb-4 pt-1" data-stars="<%= i %>" data-form-id="<%= form_id %>" id="<%= "#{form_id}_#{i}" %>"></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

JQUERY ---------------------------

```
var set_stars = function(form_id, stars){
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
      if(i <= stars){
        $('#' + form_id + '_' + i).addClass('on');
      } else {
        $('#' + form_id + '_' + i).removeClass('on');
      }
    }
  }

  $(function() {
    $('.rating_star').click(function() {
      var star = $(this);
      var form_id = $(this).attr('data-form-id');
      var stars = $(this).attr('data-stars');

      set_stars(form_id, stars);

      $('#' + form_id + '_stars').val(stars);

      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: $('#' + form_id).attr('action'),
        data: $('#' + form_id).serialize()
      });
  });

  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    $('.star_rating_form').each(function(){
      var form_id = $(this).attr('id');
      var stars = <%= @restaurant.ratings.current_user ---- HERE'S THE PROBLEM ---- %>
      set_stars(form_id, stars)
    });
  <% end %>
```

In this last part of the JQuery code (HERE'S THE PROBLEM), I need to access the number of stars the current_user voted if exists.  I tried so many things, the code works if I put <%= 4 %> or <%= @restaurant.ratings.count %> just to see if it's somenthing else. I need to access something like **@restaurant.ratings.stars.current_user**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minutes after I asked this question I discover a very simple method called `.find_by()`, and i managed to solve this issue.

Here follows the relevant code:

HTML ---------------------------

```
<%= form_for([@restaurant, @restaurant.ratings.find_by(user: current_user) || @restaurant.ratings.build], :html => {:id => "restaurant_#{@restaurant.id}_rating", :class => "star_rating_form"}) do |f| %>
```

JQUERY -------------------------

```
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    $('.star_rating_form').each(function(){
      var form_id = $(this).attr('id');
      var stars = $('#' + form_id + '_stars').val();
      set_stars(form_id, stars)
    });
  <% end %>
```

Hope this can help someone. :)

Comment: you could have also done `@rating = @restaurant.ratings.find_or_initialize_by(user: current_user)` in your controller (as you should) and then use `@rating` in your form.